# Adding session post tags to email me info

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm absolutely new to PHP and i've gotten a contact form and application form created from a demo i downloaded offline (FancyForm). My question is how do i get each input field the user fills out to be in the email it sends me?

[JS Fiddle of working POST tags](http://jsfiddle.net/MEhyD/)

In this fiddle, you can see the working post session tags that work and send in the email, however, the last one noted doesn't send. Is it because another file doesn't have that included? A PHP file?

This is my form in HTML:

```
 <form id="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="submit.php">
                            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="15%"><label for="name">Name</label></td>
                                    <td width="70%"><input type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter]]" name="name" id="name" value="<?=$_SESSION['post']['name']?>" /></td>
                                    <td width="15%" id="errOffset">&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><label for="email">Email</label></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" class="validate[required,custom[email]]" name="email" id="email" value="<?=$_SESSION['post']['email']?>" /></td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="15%"><label for="length">Telephone</label></td>
                                    <td width="70%"><input type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyNumber]]" name="telephone" id="telephone" value="<?=$_SESSION['post']['telephone']?>" /></td>
                                    <td width="15%" id="errOffset">&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><label for="subject">Subject</label></td>
                                    <td><select name="subject" id="subject">
                                        <option value="" selected="selected"> - Choose -</option>
                                        <option value="Residential Job">Residential Job</option>
                                        <option value="Commercial Job">Commercial Job</option>
                                        <option value="Repair">Repair/Patch</option>
                                        <option value="Complaint">Complaint</option>
                                        <option value="Question">Question</option>
                                    </select></td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="top"><label for="message">Message</label></td>
                                    <td><textarea name="message" id="message" class="validate[required]" cols="35" rows="5"><?=$_SESSION['post']['message']?></textarea></td>
                                    <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><label for="captcha"><?=$_SESSION['n1']?> + <?=$_SESSION['n2']?> =</label></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyNumber]]" name="captcha" id="captcha" /></td>
                                    <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />                              
                                    <?=$str?>          <img id="loading" src="img/ajax-load.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="loading" /></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </form>
                        <?=$success?>
```

Comment: trying printing your SESSION array. `echo "<pre>"; print_r($_SESSION);` and check whether is telephone set in your session.

Comment: My question is how to add more sessions to be emailed to me though. I added the telephone in after the fact. The other 3 were default, i tried to add my own telephone in. Maybe that gives you more info?